# Convert first column of file to unixtime using grep and awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I have a file (named 2n.log) that I wish to convert a human readable date and time in the first column to a unix time:

```
 2016-03-14 15:00:35,998191
 2016-03-14 15:02:19,998181
```

On the command line, if I use the date command I get the correct unix timestamp, e.g

```
 user@server1:~# date -d "2016-03-14 15:02:19" "+%s"
 1457967739
```

However, if I put the same command in awk, I get the wrong value for unix timestamp, here's the bash script I use (named 2n.sh:

> ```
> #!/bin/env bash
> grep ".*2016" 2n.log | awk -F ',' -v dt="$(date -d "$1" "+%s")" '{print dt","$2}'
> ```

And this is the output:

```
user@server1:~# sh 2n.sh
1457913600,998191
1457913600,998181`
```

Is the problem with the grep wildcard or is it with the awk declaration? I tried substituting the grep wildcard for "2016.*" and do not get any output at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not computing date from your first field, at that point shell is still in charge.  You can do this instead

```
$ awk -F, '{cmd="date -d \""$1"\" +%s"; cmd | getline date; print date, $2}' logfile
1457982035 998191
1457982139 998181
```

add `-v OFS=,` for comma separated output.

Comment: Any reason you have used `cmd` instead of just using the command in getline. Also you may want to close the pipe afterwards

Comment: that will require a struggling dance with handling the quotes correctly, it's more readable this way and easier to type.

Comment: @123 using a var or string to getline is not the point.  It is always a good practice to `close(cmd)` after `cmd|getline x`  otherwise In some case, it will surprise you. ;-) anyway, awk is nice, but should be careful when using `getline`

Answer (score 1):

this should go with your example:

```
 awk -F, -v q='"' '$0="echo "q"$(date -d"q$1q" +%s),"$2q' file|sh
```

test it:

```
kent$  cat f
2016-03-14 15:00:35,998191
2016-03-14 15:02:19,998181

kent$  awk -F, -v q='"' '$0="echo "q"$(date -d"q$1q" +%s),"$2q' f|sh
1457964035,998191
1457964139,998181
```

If you have **gnu sed**, this line works too:

```
sed -r 's/([^,]*)(,.*)/echo $(date -d"\1" +%s\2)/ge' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the language's builtin time functions instead of calling out to `date`

```
gawk -F, -v OFS=, '{gsub(/[:-]/, " ", $1); $1 = mktime($1); print}' file
```

```
perl -MTime::Piece -F, -lane '
    $F[0] = Time::Piece->strptime($F[0], "%Y-%m-%d %T")->epoch; 
    print join ",", @F
' file
```